# SQL ORDER BY next

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Подскажите пожалуйста как отсортировать в PostgreSQL(15+) такую таблицу:

```
id |  name  | next_id
1  | Test01 |  2
2  | Test02 |  3
3  | Test03 |  6
4  | Test04 |  5
5  | Test05 |  null
6  | Test06 |  4
7  | Test07 |  null
```

Требуется SQL-запрос, чтобы упорядочить по next_id столбцу — это указатель на следующую строку. Результат ожидаю такой:

```
id |  name  | next_id
1  | Test01 |  2
2  | Test02 |  3
3  | Test03 |  6
6  | Test06 |  4
4  | Test04 |  5
5  | Test05 |  null
7  | Test07 |  null
```

Необходимо считать у каждой записи поле next_id, найти эту запись и отобразить после имеющейся. Ведь это поле может меняться, поэтому сортировка по возрастанию не подойдёт и прочие хитрости.

Пока даже нет идей как это сделать изящно. Кроме циклов и временных таблиц.

Comment: Это не сортировка. Это построение дерева. См. справку по рекурсивным CTE.

Comment: Вариант, если это сортировка узнать есть ли ф-ция isnull nvl и т п, тогда `order by isnull(next_id, 100)` или большое число вместо 100. Незная isnull можно `case when` вот так `order by case when next_id is null then 100 else  next_id  end`

Comment: Все же нужна рекурсия и указание на запись, с которой нужно начинать. И что делать если next_id=null где нибудь в середине списка. Сделать изящно  или как-нибудь без дополнительных данных не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответил [уважаемый JohnH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397687/sql-order-by-next):

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, next_id) AS (SELECT * FROM table),
cte AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.next_id, t.id AS root_id, 1 AS depth
    FROM t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t t2 WHERE t.id = t2.next_id)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.name, t.next_id, cte.root_id, cte.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM t
    JOIN cte ON (t.id = cte.next_id))
SELECT cte.id, cte.name, cte.next_id
  FROM cte
 ORDER BY cte.root_id, cte.depth, cte.id;
```